# How to get text from <strike> element by beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I can extract data from any element except **<strike>some text </strike>** by beautifulsoup.

As for example,

```
<div>
    <strike class='original-price'> 150 </strike>
    <p class='sale-price'> 120 </p>
</div>
```

`sale_price = soup.find('p', class_='sale-price').text   <=====  OUTPUT:  120`

`original_price = soup.find('strike', class_='original-price').text   <==== ERROR IS OCCURRING HERE`

Error Message:
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: to follow your code I got the expected output. It seems original-price may be loaded dynamically.

Comment: perhaps provide the actual url?